# Is there a tool to produce gif from screen recording for windows

Tags: video-editing, screen-recording, gif

I started seeing people produce a short snapshot of tutorial as gif file.

Something like this

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/images/animation.gif

Is there any good software dedicated for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues to solve.

First is capturing the video you want.  Plenty of screen recorders - I'm a Linux user so I like `gtkrecordmydesktop`, at work (educational tech) we recommend Jing to our instructors.  Be aware that some of the free ones may watermark, etc. the video, or put a limit on total run time (Jing is 5 minutes max video length, the "pro" version is called Camtasia), VLC can do it too, but may require complex command line trickery.

Second, is editing any captured video, even if it is simply trimming off "useless" seconds at the start and end. Lots of stuff to choose from, from Free to free to expensive - which would be "best" depends on your actual needs (simple trimming to zoom, effects, merging videos, etc).  LightWorks, Premier, FinalCut, Windows Movie Maker, kdenlive, etc

Finally you have your video snippet! You need to convert it from whatever format it is in to your desired animated .gif image.  The video capture or editor you chose from step 1 or 2 may just be able to export it in that fashion.  Or, you can use a tool like `ffmpeg` for the conversion.

Comment: I mainly want to use that to show case my software product features, this is very informative! pretty much what I want to do. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[ShareX](https://getsharex.com) is in my opinion the best tool to do this out there.

It will capture screenshots, video, GIFs upload them automatically to your favorite service and much more.

On top of that it's free and open source. Hard to beat it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a software program called **gyazo** ([gyazo.com](https://gyazo.com/))
It has the ability to take screenshots and make gifs as you want.
It is available on windows and mac.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I just discovered quite a few options on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/5e8cyy/what_do_you_use_to_record_screen_to_gif/